# Has Miyazaki's Future Boy Conan ever been licensed for US release?

Tags: future-boy-conan, united-states

With the popularity of all things made by Miyazaki, has Future Boy Conan ever been licensed for US release?

I know it wasn't created by Studio Ghibli; are there some legal issues that might be preventing it from being released in the US?

Comment: In the US, it was released on blu-ray on November 16th, 2021. You can find more information about this release by going to the following page on blu-ray.com:  https://www.blu-ray.com/movies/Future-Boy-Conan-The-Complete-Series-Blu-ray/299664/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No, *Future Boy Conan* has not been licensed within the US.

Although, there has been plenty of speculation as to why this never happened.

Reasons people speculate include:

- being too expensive to produce
- fear of it not selling
- it being too old
- general licensing hell

Apart from these speculations, there has never been a conclusive answer, nor has it ever been said that it will never happen.

So it might still happen some day.

[Answerman](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/answerman/2015-07-14/.90419) from  Anime News Network also stated the following:

> We have no idea what's holding back the show from the US. I used to think a show like this would be a slow seller -- it didn't exactly blow up the fansub scene back in the day, either on VHS or via Bittorrent. But then again, Discotek just hit a home run with their Castle of Cagliostro Blu-ray so who knows -- it might do OK. Regardless, it's not going to happen in the foreseeable future. Throw another one on the "licensing hell" pile, and hope that, someday, something might change.